# How to protect (or pad up) injured side?

Tags: muay-thai, injury, safety

I got a soft tissue injury in my left ribs at a fight two months ago, I gave it some time to heal and I did sparring again when I stopped feeling pain but a few days ago I was clinching without any knee pads or anything around the body and I felt that injury popping up again.

Is there a way for me to cover it without having to wear the big body padding so I can keep training with it?

Also is there a way to get it healing quicker?

Comment: See a medical professional - its not generally wise to ask random internet strangers for advice on an injury!